# trying to put templateUrl as variable results $digest already in progress on direct

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to overcome an issue I have with a angular.

I have the following scenario
There is a directive that I want its templateUrl to be a variable so each time I submit a form, I'll get a different template to load.
I have a  which has inside it a directive.
Each  has its own page (hope its "best practive")
And I want as I press the submit, the variable for the template will change, here is the code

So bascally what I'm trying to do is:
1. User input something inside the form (ng-view)
2. Sends an AJAX to the server (controller)
3. Gets a list of something back (controller)
4. A popup is being opened according to the form and displays the data (directive)

But the problem is that it doesn't like that I change the templateUrl on the fly...
I'v tried reading some stuff here (I'm new with angular) and people suggested to try and use timeouts, well in my code I tried putting timeouts all over the place, I tried doing it through functions so it will have a getter/setter

Anyway I end up with this digest message...

Module:

```
var adminApp = angular.module('AdminApp', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
```

Factory:

```
adminApp.factory('urlContext', ['$timeout',function($timeout) {
var urlPaths = {
        templateUrlToUse : "",
    setTemplateUrl : function(templateUrlToSet){
        $timeout(function(){
            this.templateUrlToUse = templateUrlToSet;
        })
    },
    getTemplateUrl : function(){
        $timeout(function() {
              return this.templateUrlToUse;
        })
    }

}

return urlPaths;
}]);

adminApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
var routeProvider = $routeProvider;

    routeProvider.when('/groupsettings', {
        templateUrl : 'scripts/pages/groupsettings.html',
        controller : 'groupSettingsController'
    });

});
```

Controller:

```
adminApp.controller('groupSettingsController',function($scope, $http,urlContext,$timeout) {

$scope.searchFacebookGroupByName = function(){
    urlContext.setTemplateUrl('scripts/pages/templates/searchbygroupalias.html');
    var facebookGroupName = $scope.facebookGroupNameToSearch;
    var facebookGroupSearchSubmit = $http.get(urlContext.groups +"/search/" + facebookGroupName);
    facebookGroupSearchSubmit.success(function(response){
        $scope.groups = response;
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.toggleModal()
        })
    });
    facebookGroupSearchSubmit.error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        console.log($scope.groups);
    };
});
```

Directive:

```
adminApp.directive('modal', function (urlContext,$timeout) {
return {
  templateUrl: urlContext.getTemplateUrl() ,
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  replace:true,
  scope:true,
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.title = attrs.title;
    scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
      if(value == true)
        $(element).modal('show');
      else
        $(element).modal('hide');
    });

    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
      });
    });

    $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
      });
    });
  }
};
  });
```

Comment: templateUrl function isn't promise based....it must return string. Also you didn't set it as a reference, you are invoking the function by adding `()`. Also return from `$timeout` doesn't return to the outer function

Answer (score 0):

Changing the templateUrl dynamically is a crazy idea. Consider putting an ng-include in your directive template and control which template gets shown through that.

Comment: disagree about it being crazy to change url....it's done all the time which is why `templateUrl` accepts a function. Needs to return a string though